# Where do the clones sleep in "Star Wars"?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

What are the things clones sleep in? I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find it. All I know is that they show up in the *Clone Wars* episode "Clone Cadets".

Answer (score 5):

They were **pull-out bunks**.

According to StarWars.com, some design concepts of the clone barracks on Kamino, and such bunks, were made for *Attack of the Clones*. While not used in the movie, they were shown in *The Clone Wars* episode, *Clone Cadets*.

[image: concept art and screenshot from the episode. The concept art shows a wall full of circular doors; one is open, showing that it pulls out into a bed with a clone asleep in it. The screenshot shows a wall full of these doors, with clones standing on the floor below.]

You can read the article [here](http://www.starwars.com/news/from-concept-to-screen-kamino).

Wookieepedia also shows an image from the episode on the page titled [Bunk](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bunk/Legends) (Legends).

Comment: I’d hate sleeping in a drawer......

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Not if you were genetically engineered to love it!

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Let me introduce you to [Capsule hotels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsule_hotel), the precursor to sleeping drawers!